# How to record an array value when passed into the method?

Tags: java, arrays

So im working on some homework and I can't figure out how to make an String array[a] pass into a method in another class and be recorded as a String array there. This is kinda hard to explain since its new to me, but here is what I'm trying to do.

Tester Program:

```
Purse c = new Purse();
c.addCoin("Quarter");
c.addCoin("Penny");
c.addCoin("Nickel");
c.addCoin("Dime");

Purse d = new Purse();
d.addCoin("Nickel");
d.addCoin("Dime");
d.addCoin("Dime");
d.addCoin("Quarter");

System.out.println(c.sameCoins(d));
System.out.println("Expected: false");
```

Purse class:

```
public boolean sameCoins(Purse other)
    {
        if (array1.length != array2.length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int same = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < array2.length; x++)
            {
                if (array2[x].equals(array1[i]))
                {
                    same++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return same==array1.length;
    }
```

I know array1 and array2 aren't proper variable/names for the arrays but that just to substitute the idea I'm trying to get at.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Do you get an error message?  Is the answer coming out incorrectly?

Comment: The method you posted is for comparing, I don't get the point...

Comment: A) You don't show what those arrays are or how they're created. B) You're not passing arrays of aything anywhere.

Comment: I'm trying to pass array c over to the class purse and store it in array 1. Then pass array d over to the class purse and store it in array 2.

Comment: Add the rest of the Purse class.

Comment: Also, this is a bad way to compare two lists, and certainly a bad way compare two sets

Comment: @JanDvorak I know, but for this hw assignment we aren't allowed to use any methods from Java array or collections class.

Answer (score 1):

If `array` is field in `Purse` class than `other` purse array can be accessed in function `sameCoins` with `other.array`

Answer (score 0):

you are returning same==array1.length and you initially set same = 0 and never incremented it.